# Adding table properties to objects in array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm drawing a table dynamically from an array of objects, each object should have a left, center and right properties which are object as well.

I want to compare the object ahead to the objects that follows and find if any property is missing, if there are, I want to add `rowSpan` with the missing difference.

For example:
This

```js
const arr =[
{Left:{},Center:{},Right:{}},
{Right:{}},
{Left:{},Right:{}},
{Left:{}},
{Left:{}}
]
```

Should look like

```js
const arr =[
{Left:{rowSpan:2},Center:{rowSpan:5},Right:{}},
{Right:{}},
{Left:{},Right:{rowSpan:3}},
{Left:{}},
{Left:{}}
]
```

I also want add alignment accordingly, so if I added `rowSpan` to an object key where that key can be still be found in the object that follows, I want to add `align:bottom` to it, if it was the last key then I should add
`align:top` and if it's the only key of it's kind I want to add `align:center`

For example:

```js
const arr =[
{Left:{},Center:{},Right:{}},
{Right:{}},
{Left:{},Right:{}},
{Left:{},},
{Left:{}}
]
```

Should look like

```js
const arr =[
{Left:{align:bottom},Center:{align:center},Right:{}},
{Right:{}},
{Left:{},Right:{align:top}},
{Left:{}},
{Left:{}}
]
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Within the context of `rowSpan`, the `arr` array at index 2, 3 have objects `{Left:{},Right:{}}, {Left:{},Right:{}},`. As per the logic defined for adding `rowSpan` the output must not have any `rowSpan` corresponding to index 2 (since index 3 also has both `Left` and `Right`). Yet, the expectation is that the output array element at index 2 should be: `{Left:{},Right:{rowSpan:3}},`. Have I misunderstood the requirement - or - does the question need to be updated?

Comment: @jsN00b you understood it correctly, I mistyped. I've just edited the question.

Comment: @Andy I've only looped through the array twice and checked that the first index is less than the second one, so I would compare each element to the elements after, I couldn't do any of the heavy lifting code unfortunately :(

Comment: Okay, so you need two separate result arrays - one with only the `rowSpan` and another with only the `align` - is that correct? Or, may be you need just the one result array with both of those props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided below is one possible solution that achieves the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to transform the objects
// by adding row-span or align or both
const getNewValue = (k, v, idx, vmap, aLen, typ = 'both') => {
  // here "k" can only be "Left", "Center" or "Right"
  // get index of current element's "idx" on the "map" (parameter: "vmap")
  const currKi = vmap[k].findIndex(i => i === idx);
  // find where the next key (ie, Left, Center or Right) is present
  // by using the "map"
  const nextK = (
    currKi >= 0
    ? currKi + 1 < vmap[k].length
      ? vmap[k][currKi + 1]       // if "vmap" has the next Left, Center or Right
      : aLen                      // if "vmap" doesn't have the next L, C or R
    : -1                // if "vmap" doesn't have current "idx"
  );
  // determine the new alignment, if applicable
  const align = (
    vmap[k].length === 1
      ? 'center'
      : nextK === aLen
        ? 'top'
        : nextK >= 0
          ? 'bottom'
          : undefined
  );
  return (
    nextK >= 0 && nextK - idx > 1     // if row-span needs to be added
    ? {
        ...v,
        ...(            // add row-span if "typ" is "both" or "span"
          ['both', 'span'].includes(typ)
          ? { rowSpan: nextK - idx }      // the "number" is computed here
          : {}
        ),
        ...(            // add align if "typ" is "both" or "align"
          ['both', 'align'].includes(typ)
          ? { align }         // populate the "align"
          : {}
        )
      }
    : v
  );
};

// method to calculate row-span and/or align
const spanAndAlign = (arr, typ = 'both') => {
  // first construct a map/dictionary
  // Left: [0, 2, 3, 4]
  // Center: [0]
  // Right: [0, 1, 2]
  // keys are L, C or R. 
  // values are arrays of index where each occurs in "arr" array
  const lcrMap = arr.reduce(
    (map, obj, idx) => {
      Object.keys(map).forEach(k => {
        if (k in obj) map[k].push(idx);
      });
      return map;
    },
    {Left: [], Center: [], Right: []}
  );
  // use the "lcrMap" to transform the given array
  const res = arr.map(
    (obj, idx) => (
      Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).map(
          ([k, v]) => ([
            k,
            ['Left', 'Center', 'Right'].includes(k)     // only transform L, C or R
            ? getNewValue(k, v, idx, lcrMap, arr.length, typ)
            : v
          ])
        )
      )
    )
  );
  return res;
};

const origArr = [{
    Left: {},
    Center: {},
    Right: {}
  },
  {
    Right: {}
  },
  {
    Left: {},
    Right: {}
  },
  {
    Left: {}
  },
  {
    Left: {}
  }
];

console.log('get Span Only: ', spanAndAlign(origArr, 'span'));
console.log('get Align Only: ', spanAndAlign(origArr, 'align'));
console.log('get Span & Alighn: ', spanAndAlign(origArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments provided in the above snippet

**NOTE**

This solution employs a number of JS concepts/features such as `.reduce()`, `.map()`, `Object.fromEntries()`, `Object.entries()`, `.findIndex()`, `.includes()`, `...` spread, `?:` ternary operator, etc.